# How to search for data with wild characters using search box in a HTML Page

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, wildcard

I have a html page and there is a search box like google search written with java script.
When trying to search a string with out '&' the search results are accurate. but when searching with the & i am receiving an error like unable to connect to server and the query is being displayed.

Can any one kindly help me on how to fix this issue by accepting the '&' symbol in the string and display the records retrieved from the database.

Web Page built on Html, java script
Database - Sql server 2008

Regards,
Deva

Comment: actually what ever string you are getting from input if any special character then you have build you string with space character so your spacial character will be string not treated as spacial character.

Comment: Hi Shailender, Can you kindly pleas give one example.

Comment: suppose in your search box, user searching for "google & yahoo" so make string like -- > "google \"&\" yahoo " format so & character will treated as string.

Comment: I have tried but it is not accepting.. i am receiving the error message as unable to connect to server: and the select query is displayed

Comment: I found out the root cause for the error, in the sqlserver anything ending with &(anyletter) will be considered as a variable. so when i try to search using A'*&8*'B it doesn't return any error. So i need to change the query how it is accepting the input.